# next/image doesn't load images twice

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I use a component that has an image that loads in the home and in another url, when I use <img it works perfectly but when I use 'next/image' it loads in the home but not in the other url.

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

import { hoverScale } from "../utils/transitions";
import Image from 'next/image';


export default function TestimonialItem({ image, name, position, text }) {
  return (
    <motion.div 
      variants={hoverScale}
      whileHover='hover'
      className='max-w-[240px] min-h-full shadow-xl p-6 relative flex flex-col items-center rounded-2xl'
    >
        <div className='absolute bg-orange p-1 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center -top-10'>
          <Image 
              src={image}
              alt={`${name} Image`}
              className='rounded-full w-[70px] h-[70px] object-cover'
              width={70}
              height={70}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='pt-6'>
          <h6 className='text-purple text-xl font-bold text-center'>{name}</h6>
          <h6 className='text-purple text-md mt-2 font-semibold text-center'>{position}</h6>
          <p className='text-gray mt-2 text-md text-center'>{text}</p>
        </div>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to go with `img` if it is working. Is there a reason why you would need to use `next/image`?